# Serial Number Field Disabled - Office 2010 - WINE

Tags: 12.04, wine, microsoft-office

Ok so I managed to run msoffice installer on my ubuntu.. but I just have one small problem.. I can't choose the serial number field.. I click on it but nothing happens, Tried multiple installers .. same problem.. :s I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS and WINE 1.7.0